# Why is Jarl Ulfric abusing General Tullius?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apparently, killing his entire council was not good enough, and winning the war was unsufficiently degrading.

After a long chat with Tullius, Ulfric decides to keep on stabbing him instead of actually killing him like he said he was going to.

[image: Manlove]

How am I supposed to tell Ulfric it's enough degradation, and have him move on?

Shot from behind:

[image: Behind]

Please someone make him stop :(

Comment: If this is about a bug you're experiencing, can you rewrite your question to ask about the bug, including what you've tried so far to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because Tulius is being marked as an essential NPC for some reason, so Ulfric is stabbing him, but he isn't dying.

Do you have any primary quests which concern Tulius? If yes, you might need to complete that quest so that he could die.

Alternatively, you could try using the console(on PC only) to mark Tulius as non-essential so that he can finally be killed. The command escapes me at the moment, but it's nothing a little Google search can't fix.

Comment: I don't like the answer "try using the console"...but this seems to be valid on almost all skyrim questions.